# Why did Yoav quote the pasuk of Amalek by Edom?

Tags: king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of, amalek, bava-batra

The Gemara (Bava Basra 21b) says that Yoav misread the passuk [Deuteronomy 25:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.25.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "Eradicate the memory of Amalek" as "Eradicate the males of Amalek" and thus only killed the males of Edom.

My question is simply like this: Why would he read the passuk of Amalek and apply it to Edom? There is no mitzvah to kill Edom?

Comment: It's because Amalek is a descendant of Esav (Edom).

Comment: @Harel13 that doesn't follow.

Comment: @RabbiKaii nonetheless, that's what Rav Steinsaltz wrote in his commentary.

Comment: @Harel13 it's an ironic anomaly - similar to the fallacy of Yoav in confusing the part for the whole?

Comment: @RabbiKaii interesting, I didn't think about it like that.